# Dynamic created data not inserted global scope Arraylist data variable

Tags: android, arraylist, datamodel

I am trying to get data from internet and that will be populated in listview. I have fully functional Custom adapter named NoticeAdapter. Arraylist is not append with dynamically created object.

What is my mistake ? It already took my 8 hours to find problem.But not find. No error shown but not list view is created. If I make a simple one or two object
in onCreate method then it added to list . it works fine .

**Please Anyone help me.**
**Thanks in Advance**

```
ListView noticeList;
NoticeAdapter na;
public String title, file_link, dept, pubDate;
```

**Here I Decleare data global variable**

```
public ArrayList<NoticeModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
String serverUrl = "http://192.168.0.104/virtualclassroomapi/notice.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notice_board);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    noticeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.noticelist);
```

**Here I call to get data from Internet and save it as object in data**

```
    getDataFromServer();
```

**If here I call "getData();" then it will worked**

```
    na = new NoticeAdapter(data, getApplicationContext());
    noticeList.setAdapter(na);

}



public void getDataFromServer(){



    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, serverUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        file_link = jsonObject.getString("file_link");
                        dept = jsonObject.getString("dept");
                        pubDate = jsonObject.getString("publish_date");
```

**I test Response from server fine using Toast. but not append to data(Arraylist) global variable as new object**

```
                        data.add(new NoticeModel(title,file_link,dept,pubDate));





                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(NoticeBoard.this,"Response Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    MySingleton.getInstance(NoticeBoard.this).addToRequestQueue(request);


}
```

**Data from here inserted but not inserted from there, If I call it instead of getDataFromServer()**

```
public void getData(){



    String title = "title from varable";
    data.add(new NoticeModel(title,"something", "get","sthe"));

}
```

Comment: You need to set your adapter in _onResponse_ method after data inserted in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding data to your adapter you should to tell adapter has been changed, so call `na.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add item in it :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) 
{
NoticeModel item = new NoticeModel();
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
item.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
item.setFileLink(jsonObject.getString("file_link"));
item.setDept(jsonObject.getString("dept"));
item.setPublishDate(jsonObject.getString("publish_date"));
data.add(item);
}
```

then set your adapter after for loop :

```
na = new NoticeAdapter(data, getApplicationContext());
noticeList.setAdapter(na);
```

and mention in your adapter :

```
na.notifyDataSetChanged();
```